# Number of permutation cycles in matrix transposition

Tags: algorithms, matrices, permutations

I am trying to solve a problem on Sphere Online Judge (SPOJ) link to which is: http://www.spoj.com/problems/TRANSP/

The matrix can be thought of as a permutation and its transposition as another permutation. I need to convert the first one into another. I have found a relation between the Cycles in the Permutation and the number of swaps required as:

Minimum Swaps = Total Elements in Permutation - Number of Cycles

However, I don't know how to calculate the matrix of size $2^a 2^b$ where $a+b \leq 500000$.

Comment: The point of the problem is for you to solve it by yourself. You're not going to learn anything if someone solves it for you.

Comment: I am not asking for a complete answer. I just want to learn on how it can be done. I am just asking for ideas. Nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a simple example:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix}' = \begin{pmatrix} a & d & g \\ b & e & h \\ c & f & i \end{pmatrix}.$$
So we need to exchange $(b,d),(f,h),(c,g)$, i.e. the answer is 3. Now try to generalize this to $A \times B$ matrices. Obtain a formula, substitute $A = 2^a$ and $B = 2^b$, and find a way to efficiently compute the result modulo a small prime $p$.

When $A = 2^a$ and $B = 2^b$, things look nicer. The permutation taking a position in the original matrix to the corresponding position in the transposed matrix corresponds to left shift by an amount $a$. Suppose $g = \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$ and $a' = a/g,b' = b/g$. We can now think of the operation as a left shift by the amount $a'$ of a string of length $a'+b'$ over an alphabet of size $G = 2^g$. The number of orbits is then the number of [necklaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29) of length $a'+b'$, which has an explicit formula. (The shift amount doesn't matter since $a'$ is invertible modulo $a' + b'$ due to $(a',b')=1$.)

Comment: I had identified this way earlier. And this is not related to my question. My question is how to find the number of Permutation cycles in a matrix transposition.

Comment: How far did you get in my algorithm? Did you find a formula for arbitrary $A,B$? When $A = B$, at least, it's not that difficult. You can start with that case.

Comment: I am relying on the formula that such a matrix can be represented as: (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) and transposition as: (a,d,g,b,e,h,c,f,i). Then transposition as a product of disjoint cycles will be: (a)(b,d)(c,g)(e)(f,h)(i). Now answer would be: Total elements - Cycles or (9-6) which is same as your answer 3. For, A=B=N, answer would be simply, ((N)*(N-1))/2. Even for ranges where total elements in matrix are within order of 10^6 can be found using cycles. But, the thing is A and B are raised to 2, which increases the permutation length to be exponential. This is causing problems for me.

Comment: Ok. So suppose $N = 2^n$. How can you compute $N(N-1)/2 \pmod{p}$ efficiently? Hint: You never need to actually compute $N$.

Comment: Yes, I can easily do it using modular exponentiation. I don't have any trouble with cases a=b. Can you please elaborate on cases when a != b because in the actual question it can happen ?

Comment: I recommend you take some small cases (not necessarily powers of $2$), compute the result, and try to generalize. There is probably a simple formula in the case $A \neq B$ as well. Don't expect me to solve your problem for you.

Comment: Are you sure there exists a simple formula for A != B cases?

Comment: Added a formula for general $A,B$ which are powers of 2.